# ModuleNotFoundError in unittest when mocking class method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I want to test a method of a class. There I want to mock a method that is in another class. But I always get the error below.

### Error

```
Ran 1 test in 0.005s

FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dev\test_unittest\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1343, in patched
    with self.decoration_helper(patched,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\dev\test_unittest\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1325, in decoration_helper
    arg = exit_stack.enter_context(patching)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 448, in enter_context
    result = _cm_type.__enter__(cm)
  File "D:\dev\test_unittest\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1398, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "D:\dev\test_unittest\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1573, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "D:\dev\test_unittest\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1245, in _importer
    thing = __import__(import_path)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

### Folder Structure

[image]

### foo.py

```py
from parentfolder.handler import Handler

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.handler = Handler()

    def verify_client(self):
        client = self.handler.get_value('client')
        return client == 'client'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    re = foo.verify_client()
    print(re)
```

### handler.py

```py
class Handler:
    def get_value(self, value):
        return value
```

### test.py

```py
import unittest
import mock
from parentfolder.foo import Foo


class testFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('foo.Foo.get_value', return_value='client')
    def test_verify_client(self):
        foo = Foo()
        result = foo.verify_client()
        self.assertTrue(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your unit test code.

### Invalid import path

This is what is causing the error you are seeing. If you look at the documentation of [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), you'll see that the `target` string must be in a form that is importable from the environment you are calling `patch` from, i.e. the one where you execute your unit test in.

No module named `foo` can be directly imported from that environment because that module is located in the `parentfolder` package. So the package name must be included in the module path like this: `patch("parentfolder.foo.[...]")`

The same reason you imported the `Foo` class at the top of your `test` module by providing the `parentfolder` in the import path.

### Non-existent attribute

Even if you fix that import path, the rest of that target string is still wrong because your `Foo` class in the `foo` module does not have an attribute named `get_value`. That is a method of your `Handler` class. And if you want to patch that method, you need to write your target string like this: `patch("parentfolder.foo.Handler.get_value")`

Notice that I don't need to write the path to the `handler` module because the `Handler` class is imported into the `foo` module, meaning it will be in the namespace of `foo`, when `patch` is called. It would be equivalent in this case to write it like this: `patch("parentfolder.handler.Handler.get_value")`

### Missing test method parameter

Using `patch` as a decorator for your test method means you **must** define it with an additional parameter that takes the mock created by `patch` as the argument **or** you must provide the `new` argument to `patch`. The typical setup looks like this:

```py
@patch("parentfolder.foo.Handler.get_value")
def test_verify_client(self, mock_get_value):
    ...
```

### Why not use `unittest.mock`?

This is not that big of a deal. It is just strange, why you would install a separate package, when `mock` has been part of the standard library's `unittest` package since Python `3.3`.

### Full working example

All in all, this is how I would rewrite your `test` module:

```py
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from parentfolder.foo import Foo


class FooTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch("parentfolder.foo.Handler.get_value")
    def test_verify_client(self, mock_get_value: MagicMock) -> None:
        mock_get_value.return_value = "client"
        foo = Foo()
        result = foo.verify_client()
        self.assertTrue(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Alternatively, I like to import the module under testing itself and then just patch its namespace directly (without additional imports) using [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object), which is possible because a module (like literally everything else in Python) is an object and its namespace represents the attributes of that object. It is a matter of personal preference I suppose:

```py
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from parentfolder import foo as foo_module


class FooTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch.object(foo_module.Handler, "get_value")
    def test_verify_client(self, mock_get_value: MagicMock) -> None:
        mock_get_value.return_value = "client"
        foo = foo_module.Foo()
        result = foo.verify_client()
        self.assertTrue(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```